# Gatsby slug does not generate correct page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby, slug

My gatsby slug is not generating correct page url.
It should generate ->       /second-post-getting-started
But it's generating  ->      /second-post-getting-started/second-post-getting-started

It's adding the slug to the current page instead of going back and then adding. I've cross checked
gatsby-node.js and other pages but cannot find the mistake.

Here is the gatsby-node.js code.

```
 
const path = require('path')
const { slugify } = require('./src/util/utilityFunctions')
const authors = require('./src/util/authors')
const _ = require('lodash')

exports.onCreateNode = ({ node, actions }) => {
 const { createNodeField } = actions
 if (node.internal.type === 'MarkdownRemark') {
   const slugFromTitle = slugify(node.frontmatter.title)
   createNodeField({
     node,
     name: 'slug',
     value: slugFromTitle,
   })
 }
}

exports.createPages = async ({ actions, graphql }) => {
 const { createPage } = actions

 // Page templates
 const templates = {
   post: path.resolve('src/templates/single-post.js'),
   postList: path.resolve('src/templates/post-list.js'),
   tag: path.resolve('src/templates/tag-posts.js'),
   tagsPage: path.resolve('src/templates/tags-page.js'),
   authorPosts: path.resolve('src/templates/author-posts.js'),
 }

 const res = await graphql(`
   {
     allMarkdownRemark {
       edges {
         node {
           frontmatter {
             author
             tags
           }
           fields {
             slug
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 `)

 if (res.errors) return Promise.reject(res.errors)

 // Extracting all posts from res
 const posts = res.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges

 // Create single post pages
 posts.forEach(({ node }) => {
   createPage({
     path: node.fields.slug,
     component: templates.post,
     context: {
       // Passing slug for template to use to fetch the post
       slug: node.fields.slug,
       // Find author imageUrl from author array and pass it to template
       imageUrl: authors.find(x => x.name === node.frontmatter.author)
         .imageUrl,
     },
   })
 })

 // Create posts pagination pages
 const postsPerPage = 2
 const numberOfPages = Math.ceil(posts.length / postsPerPage)

 Array.from({ length: numberOfPages }).forEach((_, index) => {
   const isFirstPage = index === 0
   const currentPage = index + 1

   // Skip first page because of index.js
   if (isFirstPage) return

   createPage({
     path: `/page/${currentPage}`,
     component: templates.postList,
     context: {
       limit: postsPerPage,
       skip: index * postsPerPage,
       numberOfPages: numberOfPages,
       currentPage: currentPage,
     },
   })
 })
 // Get all tags
 let tags = []
 _.each(posts, edge => {
   if (_.get(edge, 'node.frontmatter.tags')) {
     tags = tags.concat(edge.node.frontmatter.tags)
   }
 })

 let tagPostCounts = {} // { tutorial: 2, design: 1}
 tags.forEach(tag => {
   // Or 0 cause it might not exist yet
   tagPostCounts[tag] = (tagPostCounts[tag] || 0) + 1
 })

 // Remove duplicates
 tags = _.uniq(tags)

 // Tags page (all tags)
 createPage({
   path: '/tags',
   component: templates.tagsPage,
   context: {
     tags,
     tagPostCounts,
   },
 })

 // Tag posts pages
 tags.forEach(tag => {
   createPage({
     path: `/tag/${_.kebabCase(tag)}`,
     component: templates.tag,
     context: {
       tag,
     },
   })
 })

 // Create author posts pages
 authors.forEach(author => {
   createPage({
     path: `/author/${slugify(author.name)}`,
     component: templates.authorPosts,
     context: {
       authorName: author.name,
       imageUrl: author.imageUrl,
     },
   })
 })
}
```

index.js code

```
       import React from "react"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import SEO from "../components/seo"
import { graphql, StaticQuery } from "gatsby"
import Post from "../components/Post"
import PaginationLinks from '../components/PaginationLinks'

const IndexPage = () => {
  const postPerPage = 2
  let numberOfPages
  return(
  <Layout pageTitle = "Full Stack Me" 
  pageSubtitle = "Just an Encyclopedia for Web Devs" >
    <SEO title="Home" keywords={[`gatsby`, `application`, `react`]} />
      <StaticQuery 
      query={indexQuery} render={data => {
        numberOfPages = Math.ceil(data.allMarkdownRemark.totalCount / postPerPage)
      return(
        <div>
          {data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.map(({ node }) => (
            <Post  
            key={node.id }
            title={node.frontmatter.title}
            author={node.frontmatter.author}
            slug={node.fields.slug}
            date={node.frontmatter.date}
            body={node.excerpt}
            fluid={node.frontmatter.images.childImageSharp.fluid}
            tags={node.frontmatter.tags}
            />
          ))}
          <PaginationLinks currentPage={1} numberOfPages={numberOfPages}/>
        </div>
      )
    }}
    />
  </Layout>
  )
}

const indexQuery = graphql`
query{
  allMarkdownRemark(
    sort: { fields: [frontmatter___date], order: DESC }
    limit: 2
    ) {
    totalCount
    edges{
      node{
        id
        frontmatter{
          title
          date(formatString: "MMM Do YYYY")
          author
          tags
          images{
            childImageSharp{
              fluid(maxWidth: 600){
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
              }
            }
          }
        }
        fields{
          slug
        }
        excerpt
      }
    }
  }
}
`

export default IndexPage
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not just linking to the wrong path (e.g. `foo` instead of `/foo`) in your HTML/JSX?

Comment: Where can i get that file.  If you want to have a look here is the git repo [link](https://github.com/Swapnil-Sagar/FullStackME)

Answer (score 1):

You are linking to `{slug}` when the `slug` is not prefixed with a forward slash:

```
<Link to={slug}>{/* No slash at the beginning */}
  <Img className="card-image-top" fluid={fluid} />
</Link>
```

([source](https://github.com/Swapnil-Sagar/FullStackME/blob/49e24da740bcb1686754bf2a49619ad965c2a89d/src/components/Post.js#L16))

This makes it a [path-relative URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#Absolute_URLs_vs_relative_URLs). If you are viewing a page at `/foo/` and link to `href="bar"`, the full URL path will be `/foo/bar`. You almost certainly want to be using absolute paths, but hostname relative, URLs, which you can do by ensuring you always start the URL with a slash:

```
<Link to={`/${slug}/`}>{/* With starting and trailing slashes */}
  <Img className="card-image-top" fluid={fluid} />
</Link>
```